# Necessity of using an accelerator with CA glue?

Tags: glue, filler

I notice that various web articles on using CA glue to do wood filling the authors generally recommend using an accelerator, like baking soda or a professional accelerator.

What is the necessity of using an accelerator? I thought that superglue dries in like 10 minutes or less anyway, why do we need to rush it?

My primary use would be making do-it-yourself fillers using sawdust, so fast drying might be a disadvantage because I would have only seconds to apply the filler before the glue hardened.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use an accelerator with CA glue.  It is just that, an accelerator.  Thick glue in a wide joint will take a few minutes or more to set, but with the accelerator it's cured in a few seconds.  If you don't mind clamping your work up you don't need to use accelerator at all.  If you have a situation where you want more open time then you should not use accelerator.

The faster curing that the accelerator can cause can also lead to more hazing.

However, it is really, really handy to just squeeze your pieces for a few seconds and then have a permanent bond.

Comment: Ok, so in my situation where I am using it to make filler, a longer setting is preferable, so I should not use an accelerator then.

Comment: I could see a use-case where you (quickly) make a paste, get it where you want it, and then hit it with the accelerator to lock it in...but I don't really think it's necessary.

Comment: Every time I make a wood paste with CA glue it always comes out looking too dark and somewhat "plasticky." I'd use a clear-drying wood glue or even just Elmer's white glue and just wait an hour or so before sanding it etc.